# Partial merge join behavior if the right table is already sorted according to the join key

Tags: clickhouse

I am evaluating different joins algorithms for a use case described below and looking for a clarification on the documentation.
When explaining the partial merge join algorithm the documentation mentions that:

> First ClickHouse sorts the right table by join key in blocks and
> creates min-max index for sorted blocks. Then it sorts parts of left
> table by join key and joins them over right table. The min-max index
> is also used to skip unneeded right table blocks.

Which makes sense, but what if both the left and right table are already sorted on disk according to the join key? Does Clickhouse still sort the right table again and dump it on disk in the same order? If yes, is that an intended behavior?

Specific use case:
Left table:

```
CREATE TABLE default.spans (
    `project_id` UInt64, 
    `transaction_span_id` UInt64, 
    `transaction_name` LowCardinality(String), 
    `span_id` UInt64, 
    `transaction_finish_ts` DateTime, 
    `deleted` UInt8,
    `retention_days` UInt16,
    ... MANY MORE COLUMNS ....
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(deleted) 
PARTITION BY toMonday(transaction_finish_ts) 
ORDER BY (
    project_id, 
    toStartOfDay(transaction_finish_ts), 
    transaction_name, 
    cityHash64(transaction_span_id),
    cityHash64(span_id),
) 
TTL transaction_finish_ts + toIntervalDay(retention_days)
```

Right table:

```
CREATE TABLE default.transactions_local (
    `project_id` UInt64, 
    `span_id` UInt64, 
    `transaction_name` LowCardinality(String), 
    `finish_ts` DateTime, 
    `retention_days` UInt16, 
    `deleted` UInt8, 
    ... A LOT MORE COLUMNS ...
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(deleted) 
PARTITION BY (retention_days, toMonday(finish_ts)) 
ORDER BY (
    project_id, 
    toStartOfDay(finish_ts), 
    transaction_name, 
    cityHash64(span_id)
) 
TTL finish_ts + toIntervalDay(retention_days)
```

Join key:

```
spans.project_id = transact.project_id AND 
toStartOfDay(spans.transaction_finish_ts) = toStartOfDay(transact.finish_ts) AND
spans.transaction_name = transact.transaction_name AND
cityHash64(spans.transaction_span_id) = cityHash64(transact.span_id)
```

The join would be n:1 with n records of the left table corresponding to one of the right table.

So the the four conditions in the join key are the same first fields in the ORDER BY clause of both tables.
Which means that none of the tables should need to be re-sorted.

(asked as an issue one week ago [here](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/28670))

Thanks,
Filippo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which makes sense, but what if both the left and
> right table are already sorted on disk according to the join key?

Clickhouse does not use table's order and tabls' indexes.

> Which means that none of the tables should need to be re-sorted.

It does not matter. CH unable to use it. It's kinda impossible to use with the current query pipeline.

There is no near plans to improve joins (implement merge join), because they does not fit into current architecture.